# How can I group different levels of a categorical predictor X using a binary response variable Y

Tags: r, variables, grouping, levels

I am using a Logistic Regression to predict a binary response variable Y (0/1) using multiple quantitative and categorical variables. Before training the model, I'd like to group different levels of a categorical predictor X, because it has too many levels (e.g. reducing the number of levels from 12 to 2 or 3).

I want the levels to be grouped using the binary response variable Y, i.e the final groups must be different from each other in regards to Y. For example, if the levels of X are grouped into 2 groups A and B, then the rate of Y=1 of all observations whose variable X is a level from group A **must be significantly different** from the rate of Y=1 of all observations whose variable X is a level from group A.

What algorithm could do such a grouping ? And is there a package in R ?

I don't mind if the algorithm requires the desired number of groups as an input.

Thanks (and sorry for the english).

Comment: What do your variables represent?  There may be a better way to do the grouping.  Your plan does not sound like a statistically valid way to group levels of a predictor.

Comment: Each observation represents a client who subscribed a certain internet provider (let's call it AAA). The response variable Y is the churn (= 1 if a client unsubscribed AAA to go to a competitor, 0 if not).

There are a lot of various numeric and categorical data. Categorical data can represent the geographical state where the customer lives, type of reclamation, type of shop where he first subscribed, type of work, etc.

Comment: which variables do you want to combine levels for?

Comment: Any variable who has too many levels (let's say more than 5).

Also, would a decision tree using a one-hot encoded categorical variable work ? For a given categorical variable X, which has levels a, b, c, ... z, I would train a decision tree with predictors Xa, Xb, Xc, ... Xz who are all binary, to predict Y. Then I use the branches to figure out the groups ?